# what causes "permission denied"-message with FIREBASE and FLUTTER

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, flutter

I've got the error

> 'W/SyncTree(31625): Listen at /address failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied'

while sending a request to firebase with an anonymous firebase user and without fancy firebase database rules :) . ..and i want to find out what causes this message.

EDIT: error is the same with an existing user, means user signIn seems to work but accessing database not.

**What i've done so far:**

- Set up firebase (including adding google_service.json, dependencies in pubspec.yaml) - works so far
- creating login as follows (like in example from google [link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#-example-tab-)):

  ```
  Future<String> _testSignInAnonymously() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
    assert(user != null);
    assert(user.isAnonymous);
    assert(!user.isEmailVerified);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
    assert(user.providerData.length == 1);
    assert(user.providerData[0].providerId == 'firebase');
    assert(user.providerData[0].uid != null);
    assert(user.providerData[0].displayName != null);
    assert(user.providerData[0].photoUrl == null);
    assert(user.providerData[0].email != null);

    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    print(currentUser.uid);
    print(currentUser.isAnonymous);
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    return 'signInAnonymously succeeded: $user';
  }
  ```
- the print statement provides a userId (and this id is also in firebase auth section) --> seems to me that i've got an logged in user
- implement kind of initialization like in the google example ([link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_database#-example-tab-)):

  ```
  Future<void> main() async {
    final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
      name: 'mydbName',
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
         googleAppID: 'myAppId',
         apiKey: 'myApiKey',
         databaseURL: 'myUrl',
      ),
   );
   runApp(new MyApp(app));
  }
  ```
- on another stateful widget in state i try to request some firebase data:

  ```
  void initState() {
    final FirebaseDatabase database = new FirebaseDatabase(app: widget.app);
    database.reference().child('address').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Connected to database and read ${snapshot.value}');
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  ```
- i've removed all rules in firebase except:

  ```
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null",
  ```
- i use an SHA-1 certificate/fingerprint in my `firebase android app`
- i use the same firebase database with an `firebase ios app` without any problem while using anonymous users

**What i need:**

I need some hint how to find out if there's any problem with that initialization code or with the user login or something else

Comment: You also downloaded the google-services.json to `android/app/google-services.json`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes, i do

Comment: Did you push the rules to this database `name: 'mydbName',` as well or only to the default database?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i push the rules into my database `https://mydbName.firebaseio.com/`. i hope these rules are used for both with this database associated apps (ios and android)?! and my ios app works with it

Comment: Have you checked in the console the rules are there in the specified database? The rules are per database. Have you check with the simulator in the firebase console? The same rules apply for iOS and Android, but not automatically for `mydbName` and the default database.

Comment: What happens if you comment out this line `name: 'mydbName',`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if i comment out this line, i got: `'name != null': is not true` and 'name is required'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the database is not correctly addressed in `FirebaseApp.configure(`

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(...)
```

would use the default database of the project configured in `google-services.json`

Comment: This 'workaround' solution solves my problem, thx :) if i'll find the problem within the configuration i'll post it